# How do I create a List<Item<T>>

Tags: c#, generics

Just trying to get my head around this one.  Consider the following code.

```
public class Setting<T> where T: struct
{
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsDto
{
    public List<Setting<>> Settings{ get; set; }
}
```

The issue is in the SettingsDto class. My Settings property wants me to specify a type for List>.  All I know right now is that T must be a struct. How can I create a list of Settings such that I can add to it later - perhaps at runtime.  Is there a way around this ?

Many thanks for all replies.

Comment: `public class SettingsDto<T>`? wouldn't named properties be better?

Comment: You need to define a type for `Setting` as well. You need to pass along whatever data type you want `Value` to be.

Comment: I dont want to specify T at the SettingsDto level.  I might want to add settings of type int, decimal and long etc. So I cant enforce this on the dto.

Answer (score 3):

You can carry over the generic parameter over to `SettingsDto`:

```
public class SettingsDto<T> where T : struct
{
    public List<Setting<T>> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must to pass T generic type to SettingsDto.

Try this:

```
public class Setting<T> where T: struct 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsDto<T> where T: struct
{
    public List<Setting<T>> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it if all settings have something in common. Consider using an interface like this:

```
public interface ISetting
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Setting<T> : ISetting
    where T : struct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsDto
{
    public List<ISetting> Settings { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var set=new SettingsDto();
        set.Settings=new List<ISetting>();
        set.Settings.Add(new Setting<int>() { Name="Setting1", Value=100 });
        set.Settings.Add(new Setting<double>() { Name="Setting2", Value=Math.PI });
        set.Settings.Add(new Setting<DateTime>() { Name="Setting3", Value=DateTime.Now });
        set.Settings.Add(new Setting<int>() { Name="Setting4", Value=200 });

        foreach(var setting in set.Settings.OfType<Setting<int>>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", setting.Name, setting.Value);
        }
        // Setting1=100
        // Setting4=200
    }
}
```

Comment: @ja72, This will only work for ints. Not really a solution.

Comment: @all. The issue I was having when I explored the Interface and abstract class route, was getting back my list of Settings. If I base Setting<T> on an abstract class or interface, then call a list of the base class, the list does not expose the .Value property.

Comment: And that's why you have to use the `.OfType<>()` extension method in order to get the type you need. In the example I used `.OfType<Setting<int>>` but I could have used `.OfType<Setting<DateTime>>` instead. It works for _any_ type.

Answer (score 0):

Does it has to be struct? Otherwise You could use

```
public List<Setting<object>> Settings { get; set; }
```

and cast it when needed.

If it is not for performance reasons, you could put the struct inside a class.